# Grothendieck Group - why not the free abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, universal-property, free-abelian-group

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group), given $M$ a commutative monoid, the Grothendieck group $K$ is an abelian group satisfying a homomorphism, 
$i:M\rightarrow K$ s.t. for any homomorphism $f:M \rightarrow A$ into an abelina group $A$, there exists a unique homomorphism $g:K \rightarrow A$ such that $g \circ i = f $.

---

Sorry, maybe this is obvious, but why couldn't we take $K = Z(M)$, the [free abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Universal_property) generated by $M$, instead of quotienting out a subgroup? Does not the universal property of $K$ follow from the universal property of $Z(M)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical inclusion $i:M\to Z(M)$ is not a homomorphism.  Given $a,b\in M$, $i(a)+i(b)$ will be the formal sum of $a$ and $b$ as elements of $Z(M)$, which is different from $i(a+b)$.  Basically, $Z(M)$ completely forgets about the monoid structure of $M$ and treats $M$ as just a set, and so $i$ will not preserve that structure.

Comment: We quotient by the smallest subgroup of Z(M) which will fix this, in fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so does this imply: If $i:M \rightarrow A$, $M$ a monoid, $A$ an abelian group, is a mapping that maps identity to identity, then by taking quotient of subgroup generated by $i(m+n)-i(m)-i(n)$ for all $m,n \in M$, $i$ becomes a homomorphism? Then why we need $M$ to be commutative?

Comment: That correct.  Commutativity of $M$ is irrelevant.